# Terraria: Witch Doctor not spawning despite me killing the Queen Bee (in a friend's duplicate server of my world)

Tags: terraria

I'm pretty new to Multiplayer Terraria. My friend recently got **my world files** and we played together. We decided to hunt the Queen Bee as I wanted to get the Witch Doctor to join my city. I asked him whether it would work if we'd fight the Queen Bee in that particular server, would the Witch Doctor appear in my village, and responded 'Yes'. So we destroyed Queen Bee and I went back to my ordinary server.
This is the part I don't understand:

The path we dug through the underground jungle into the hive was clearly shown on my mini-map, **although** the path we dug through was untouched.

I've been waiting with a valid **jungle** house, (following what was said throughout the wikis and guides) however, the Witch Doctor has not shown up for the past 2 game days.

I'm planning to repeat the same procedure in Single Player (as the larvae has only been destroyed in the duplicate world [like all the other blocks we destroyed along our path]) and hopefully, he would come. Before I do this tomorrow, could it be some other reason the Witch Doctor is not spawning?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you mean you fought the Queen bee on a copy of your world? If so, the witch hunter will not spawn on your original world.
It only works on the world you effectively killed the Queen Bee.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like this is what happened:

1. You had your world file. We'll call it **World A**.
2. You copied your world file and gave it to your friend. We'll call that **World A Copy**.
3. You and your friend dug through the Jungle, then discovered and defeated a Queen Bee in **World A Copy**.
4. You went back to your own **World A**. The minimap shows what you did in **World A Copy** but the world itself does not match the minimap.

The information about whether you defeated a Queen Bee (or other bosses) is recorded in the world file, so you will need to defeat a Queen Bee again in **World A**.

Or you could have your friend give you the **World A Copy** file and replace your old **World A** file with it.

The reason the minimap does not match the world is because the minimap is stored with the player files, not the world files. Each world file has an internal ID number that connects it with a player's minimap files. Because you copied a world, both **World A** and **World A Copy** have the same ID number, so Terraria uses the same minimap for both worlds.

Comment: I see you've asked several questions recently. Please consider accepting answers by clicking the checkmark.